# Different gravatars for same person

Tags: bug, gravatar

<s>(solved, an edit updated the gravatar)</s>

This is the first time I see a user which has on the [personal page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22676/per-mildner) a blue gravatar, but [otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168429/how-to-convert-a-code-that-is-using-atom-to-term-from-swi-prolog-to-sicstus-prol/20173128#20173128) has another color (whose name escapes me for the moment).

I assume this is an error, as also other things (like the updating of personal statistics, top-users) were odd in the last week or so.

EDIT: Editing only temporarily updated the gravatar, now the old mauve color is back. ((Mauve is good for databases, because it has the most RAM. [Proof](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Database%20Mauve)))

[image: personal page]

[image: an answer showing another gravatar]

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, your theory was just confirmed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: really? I see the same avatar as in the screenshot still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters super weird, I can swear it was fine but now back to that other one again. Hmm... it was fine when I clicked the "this post was edited, click here to reload" meaning the AJAX call brought back the correct, new, hash. Care to edit again so I'll reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

Caching, it almost invariably comes down to caching.

Most likely the person recently changed their email address in their profile, leading to a different gravatar. The posts, using cached data, still show the old.

You could, to confirm, make an edit to one of their posts; I bet you that the gravatar updates too.

Comment: Actually the email might and is most likely the same. Stack Exchange added salt to the hash some time ago meaning most gravatars have been changed behind the scenes.

Comment: True. But only for the edit post, not the others. How long should it take to be in sync?

Comment: I don't know; some aspects are cached in the database ('baked'), and not updated until the post is edited. In this case, the AJAX response uses new data, the page itself is still using old.

Comment: The problem is still present. Sure this is caching related?

Comment: There are different caches, some of which only are updated with a post. That said, this one is awfully persistent.