# HNQ gravatar display bug

Tags: bug, hot-questions, profile-picture, gravatar

I was browsing the HNQs (Hot network questions) when I saw that some of the gravatars had different usernames, but the same gravatar. When investigating further, I found that in fact, they all belong to different users, and those users have profile pictures that are not the same as those displayed on the HNQ page. Here is an example from page 1 (around UTC 1900)

[image: Page 1 display error]

And another example from page 3 (around 19:05)

[image: Page 3 display error]

However, when I click on the profiles of the generic green Gravatar icon for any of the below users, such as [Darth Biomech](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/80125/darth-biomech) on Worldbuilding SE, it takes me to their profile page on that site... with a completely different profile picture. As this is a recurring bug (the same happened for all the other ones I clicked on) is this a problem with my device/browser/operating system (I'm using Windows 10 on a PC on Chrome) or is this a larger, site-wide bug?

Edit: Just checked for the other Gravatars; they seem to work fine as the bug only occurs with the teal/white generic one.

Comment: I don't have specifics but I don't actually think this is limited to the HNQ lists. I have other pages I've used where I've seen this default gravatar, too.

Comment: The identicon there is the [default Gravatar image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1). Poking around Darth Biomech's mod history, it's not clear why it does that in HNQ. Their SO profile does not have that listed (I've seen some really old profiles that do, but that was likely an old bug)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different gravatars for same person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217812/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266914/282094

Comment: Closed question as duplicate as the same question (or a version of it) was asked and is linked at top of page. Thank you.